# django modelForm filter isn't effective?

Tags: python, django

As said the title. I don't understand why the filter in the ModelForm for classeur isn't working. It return all column form the database (in the associate form) as if I write Classeur.objects.all().

Model :

```
  class Document(models.Model):
      classeur = models.ForeignKey(Classeur, verbose_name=u"classeur", null=True)
      #some other attribute
  class Classeur(models.Model):
       type_classeur = models.ForeignKey(TypeClasseur)
       #some other attribute
```

ModelForm:

```
class DocumentFidsourceForm(forms.ModelForm):

    classeur = Classeur.objects.filter(type_classeur=1).order_by('rang')
    #some piece of code

    class Meta:
        model = Document
```

Views.py :

```
 form = DocumentFidsourceForm()
    return render_to_response('documents/createDoc.html',
                          {'form': form,
                           #other param}
```

the template :

```
 <table align="center" cellspacing="5" class="table_form">
        <tr>
            <td class="label">{{form.classeur.label|safe}} : </td>
            <td class="box">{{form.classeur}}</td>
```

For the context, i have a model Classeur with many attribut and around 4000 entry in the DB. Running django 1.6

When i do a select as below on the db , i have 15 result (the "good" result).

```
Select * from classeur where type_classeur_id = 1
```

So the answer could be ?: I can't make a filter on Classeur in the modelForm (suppose i can).

There a hidden things in django 1.6 which convert my filter to display ALL the values and let the user choice ( which is pretty embarassing when you have a select with ~~4000 values but nervermind for a machine).

I did something dumb (currently trying to evolve a 1.1 to 1.6 django website).

Thinqs for your light.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a [ModelChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield) to create a select input from a queryset.

For example:

```
class DocumentFidsourceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    classeur = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Classeur.objects.filter(type_classeur=1).order_by('rang')
    )
    #some piece of code

    class Meta:
        model = Document
```

If `Document.classeur` should always be filtered, then you can edit your field definition on the `Document` model to use [limit_choices_to](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to):

```
class Document(models.Model):
    classeur = models.ForeignKey(
        Classeur,
        limit_choices_to={'type_classeur__id': 1},
        verbose_name=u"classeur",
        null=True
    )
    #some other attribute
```